# ¿Por qué me aparece que tengo un campo ambiguo?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenos días estoy realizando una consulta `sql` en `sql server` y arroja un error; "campo número es ambiguo", alguien que me ayude a identificar el error en esta pequeña consulta, Muchas Gracias.

```
SELECT id, numero, referencia, cantidad FROM dbo.factura2_2000 
INNER JOIN dbo.factura1_2000 ON dbo.factura2_2000.numero = dbo.factura1_2000.numero

WHERE dbo.factura1_2000.anulado = 0 AND mes BETWEEN '200909' 
                                    AND '200912' AND referencia = '8600310'
GROUP BY mes, referencia, numero
ORDER BY referencia ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que en la consulta el campo `numero` aparece en dos tablas diferentes y en el `Select` o `Group By` no se especifica a que tabla se refiere

Según tu ejemplo debe ser `factura2_2000.numero` o `factura1_2000.numero`

Answer (score 1):

Lo que supongo es que en tus dos tablas; `factura1_200` y `factura2_2000` tienes un campo llamado: `numero`, entonces `sql` no entiendo cual campo debe tomar en consideración, entonces debes asignarle al `select` a quien le pertenece el campo, supongo que deseas obtener el `numero` que esta en la `factura1_2000`, entonces debes llamarlo así: `dbo.factura1_2000.numero`, tu sentencia quedaría algo así:

```
SELECT id, dbo.factura1_2000.`numero`, referencia, cantidad 
FROM dbo.factura2_2000
INNER JOIN dbo.factura1_2000 ON dbo.factura2_2000.numero = dbo.factura1_2000.numero
WHERE dbo.factura1_2000.anulado = 0 AND mes BETWEEN '200909' 
AND '200912' AND referencia = '8600310'
GROUP BY mes, referencia, dbo.factura1_2000.`numero`
ORDER BY referencia ASC
```